# How does android decide to cache a process

Tags: android

In Gingerbread Settings->Applications->MyApplications, the Running tab 
has been divided into two. Running Services and Cached Background 
Process. So how and when does Android decide to cache a process? 
Mainly is there anything my app can do to tell the system to never 
cache my process? 
Thanks 
KK

Answer (score 0):

It seems like someone (or you?) cross posted the same [question](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/0f708aa0f28af52b/bc07ab2daf78fa34?pli=1) from Android Developers forum. Relinked [answer](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/msg/efce0054907bfd77) from Mark Murphy for others' convenience.

Answer (score 0):

I think Android keeps track of the process that are been frequently been in use of different components and different apps and cached them.